# Can't access objects stored in an ArrayList

Tags: java, list, netbeans

I created an arraylist.

```
List FWD = new ArrayList<Coords>();
FWD.add(new Coords(42.41, 37.23));
FWD.add(new Coords(37.09, 47.8));
FWD.add(new Coords(36.83, 48.42));
```

and then I want to access each element of the list in this way:

```
FWD.get(3).[some method from Coords class]
```

but Netbeans says:

> cannot find symbol   symbol:   method getIndexX()   location: class
>   Object

Coords class:

```
public class Coords {
    private double weightY, indexX;

    Coords(double x, double y){
        setIndexX(x);
        setWeightY(y);
    }

    public double getWeightY() {
        return weightY;
    }

    public void setWeightY(double weightY) {
        this.weightY = weightY;
    }

    public double getIndexX() {
        return indexX;
    }

    public void setIndexX(double indexX) {
        this.indexX = indexX;
    }
}
```

Comment: `List<Coords> FWD = new ArrayList<Coords>();`. Also arrays are 0 base indexed, so it should be `FWD.get(2);` to get the last element in your list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable FWD is of type `List`, but it actually contains an `ArrayList<Coords>`, which is a `List<Coords>`, but the compiler does not know this. If `FWD` is declared as a `List<Coords>` this code should work as is.

You should also note that Java lists are 0-indexed, so the third element of the list has an index of 2, so in the example you have provided there will not be an element retrieved, although this will only appear at runtime.

As a final point, it may be interesting to note that Java convention dictates variables to be named in camelCase with, so you may prefer to name your variable `fwd` or similar (Perhaps using a full words if not too excessive).

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
List FWD = new ArrayList<Coords>();
```

To:

```
List<Coords> FWD = new ArrayList<Coords>();
```

Comment: this one looks better (can use it since java 1.7)
List<Coords> FWD = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
List<Coords> FWD = new ArrayList<Coords>();
```

This way the compiler knows that FWD holds list of `Coords`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using

```
List FWD = new ArrayList<Coords>();
```

which means the JVM would create List as follows

```
List<Object> FWD = new ArrayList<Coords>();
```

and when you use `get()`, it will return object of `Object` class and when you call method `getIndexX()`, this method does not exists in the `Object` class hence it will give an exception or error at the compiletime.

Hence, you should use

```
List<Coords> FWD = new ArrayList<Coords>();
```